# How to choose the Redux state shape for an app with list/detail views and pagination?

Tags: javascript, redux, ngrx

Imagine I have a number of entries(say, users) in my database. I also have two routes, one for list, other for detail(where you can edit the entry). Now I'm struggling with how to approach the data structure.

I'm thinking of two approaches and a kinda combination of both.

### Shared data set

- I navigate to `/list`, all of my users are downloaded from api a stored in redux store, under the key `users`, I also add some sort of  `users_offset` and `users_limit` to render only part of the of the list
- I then navigate to `/detail/<id>`, and store `currently_selected_user` with `<id>` as the val... which means I will be able to get my user's data with something like this `users.find(res => res.id === currently_selected_user)`
- updating will be nice and easy as well, since I'm working with just one data set and detail pointing to it
- adding a new user also easy, again just working with the same list of users

Now the problem I have with this approach is that, when the list of users gets huge(say millions), it might take a while to download. And also, when I navigate directly to `/detail/<id>`, I won't yet have all of my users downloaded, so to get data for just the one I need, I'm gonna have to first download the whole thing. Millions of users just to edit one.

### Separated data set

- I navigate to `/list`, and instead of downloading all of my users from api, I only download a couple of them, depending on what my `users_per_page` and `users_current_page` would be set to, and I'd probably store the data as `users_currently_visible`
- I then navigate to `/detail/<id>`, store `currently_selected_user` with `<id>` as the val...and instead of searching through `users_currently_visible` I simply download user's data from api..
- on update, I'm not gonna update `users_currently_visible` in any way
- nor will I on add

What I see as possible problem here is that I'm gonna have to, upon visiting `/list`, download data from api again, because it might not be in sync with what's in the database, I also might be unnecessarily downloading users data in detail, because they might be incidentally already inside my `users_currently_visible`

### some sort of frankenstein-y shenanigans

- I detail, I do the same as in *Separated data set* but instead of directly downloading user's data from api, I first check:

  - do I have any `users_currently_visible`
  - if so, is there a user with my id between them?
    if both are true, I then use it as my user data, otherwise I make the api call
- same happens on update, I check if my user exists between `users_currently_visible` if so, I also update that list, if not I do nothing

This would probably work, but doesn't really feel like it's the proper way. I would also probably still need to download fresh list of `users_currently_visible` upon visiting `/list`, because I might have added a new one..

Is there any fan favorite way of doing this?... I'm sure every single one redux user must have encountered the same things.

Thanks!

Comment: In our app, we're currently using the "separated data set" approach. It makes more calls to your API but it works. But anyway, it feels like the *right* approach would be using a single data set. I'm not sure on this also.

Comment: I think it comes down to how many entries you have in the database, this http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos is 5000 items and it's already 900kb..

Comment: Yes, you're right. But conceptually, it feels that the right approach is to use the same data set. Anyway, we try to look at these two entries in app state as the following: a succinct list containing only the data needed to show the list and a detailed object containing all the props when adding, editing, etc. It is technically better but I would like to have all in just one data set without having performance problems :)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Please consult [“real world” example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world) from Redux repo.
It shows the solution to exactly this problem.

Your state shape should look like this:

```
{
  entities: {
    users: {
      1: { id: 1, name: 'Dan' },
      42: { id: 42, name: 'Mary' }
    }
  },
  visibleUsers: {
    ids: [1, 42],
    isFetching: false,
    offset: 0
  }
}
```

Note I’m storing `entities` (ID -> Object maps) and `visibleUsers` (description of currently visible users with pagination state and IDs) separately.

This seems similar to your “Shared data set” approach. However I don’t think the drawbacks you list are real problems inherent to this approach. Let’s take a look at them.

> Now the problem I have with this approach is that when then list of users gets huge(say millions), it might take a while to download

You don’t need to download all of them! Merging all downloaded entities to `entities` doesn’t mean you should query all of them. The `entities` should contain all entities that have been downloaded **so far**—not all entities in the world. Instead, you’d only download those you’re currently showing according to the pagination information.

> when I navigate directly to /detail/, I wouldn't yet have all of my users downloaded, so to get data for just the one, I'm gonna have to download them all. Millions of users just to edit one.

No, you’d request just one of them. The response action would fire, and reducer responsible for `entities` would merge **this single entity** into the existing state. Just because `state.entities.users` may contain more than one user doesn’t mean you need to download all of them. Think of `entities` as of a cache that doesn’t *have* to be filled.

---

Finally, I will direct you again to the [“real world” example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world) from Redux repo. It shows exactly how to write a reducer for pagination information and entity cache, and [how to normalize JSON in your API responses with `normalizr`](https://github.com/gaearon/normalizr) so that it’s easy for reducers to extract information from server actions in a uniform way.

Comment: This example is great, but the entities accumulate overtime in the state. How can you remove the entities you don't need ?

Comment: You can't. If your app is intended to be used for days without closing the tab, this approach won't work for you, and you might be better served by something like Relay. Or you can implement your own sort of "garbage collection" on top of this approach. Or just refresh the page once in a while :-).

Comment: Updated link for the "real world" example: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world

Comment: So let me ask this, what if I want to keep track of `userVideos` where based on the "real world" example I would create pagination listening for my three list videos actions: `LIST_VIDEOS_REQUEST`,  `LIST_VIDEOS_SUCCESS` and `LIST_VIDEOS_ERROR`.  This works fine until I have another action set that I want to update the state eg. `CREATE_VIDEO_SUCCESS`

Comment: How is this supposed to work if your "master" entity has a different (smaller, less detailed) model than your "details" entity? In that case, you'd have no choice but to use a different slice of state for "master" and "details".

Comment: @JonGunter Been thinking about the same... Currently my app fetches the cached user from `entities.user[id]` and uses it to optimistically fill the details page while it does a request in the background to fetch all the details. So `entities.user` contains a mixed bag. Some users have only some fields, other users have all fields (once that details were fetched for). The upside of this is that you very quickly see some of the details filled in the details page for any user that was already fetched. The details page *always* does a fetch request so entity becomes up-to-date with the DB.

Comment: @JonGunter Thats exactly the problem I am facing right now, regarding the architecture of my app. We have an endpoint which returns some aggregated fields for the list view (say, categories list with the current number of products), but the individual category model wont have that field. I am thinking of maintaining a different store for the list view which tracks the pagination/search etc and different store for the individual models.

Comment: I can't find "visibleUsers" in the referenced source - this example must have changed?

Comment: @StijndeWitt I know it's been a long time since your comment but I have to ask: How do you keep status of entity that is loading? Imagine your entity list is empty, so you can't pre-fill it with any data, you obviously fetch the API, where do you store "loading" status? Inside each entity (as an additional property)?

Answer (score 0):

I also used `normalizr` approach before to normalize entities, but the problem with it is that this requires manual work.

If you know Apollo in GraphQL world, you probably know that it supports automatic normalisation, so data for a given object is not stored in multiple places. Thx to that they also support automatic updates, if your server responds with an object with the same id but with updated attrs, Apollo will recognize it and update this object in multiple places.

However, why this luxury should be reserved only for GraphQL? Due to this reason I implemented [redux-requests](https://github.com/klis87/redux-requests) library, which supports automatic normalisation for any API, REST, GraphQL, Firebase, whatever. How does it work? Imagine you have a book list and detailed endpoints. To communicate with them, you would just dispatch Redux actions like that:

```js
const fetchBooks = () => ({
  type: FETCH_BOOKS,
  request: { url: '/books' },
  meta: { normalize: true },
});

const fetchBook = id => ({
  type: FETCH_BOOK,
  request: { url: `/books/${id}` },
  meta: { normalize: true },
})
```

Now, to update title of a book in both places, we would just do:

```js
const updateBookTitle = (id, newTitle) => ({
  type: UPDATE_BOOK_TITLE,
  request: { url: `books/${id}`, method: 'PATCH', data: { newTitle } },
  meta: { normalize: true },
})
```

If you are interested with such an approach, more about it could be read [here](https://redux-requests.klisiczynski.com/docs/tutorial/10-automatic-normalisation)