# How to get best practice React Redux nested array data?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have data that look like this:

```
{[{id: "1",
stories: [{
    id: "11",
    items: [{ id:"111", title:"bla bla" },{ id:"222", title:"bla bla" },{ id:"333", title:"bla bla" }]
}]
```

its array of objects that have 3 levels of items.

how do i manage it in the best practice in redux?

Comment: You might be interested in an answer to a similar question by the author of Redux here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940015/how-to-choose-the-redux-state-shape-for-an-app-with-list-detail-views-and-pagina/33946576#33946576

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/gaearon/normalizr. It allows you to describe nested data as collections of schemas. For your example, I think you could use:

```
import { normalize, Schema, arrayOf } from 'normalizr';

const collection = new Schema('collections');
const story = new Schema('stories');
const item = new Schema('items');

collection.define({
   stories: arrayOf(story)
});

story.define({
   items: arrayOf(item)
})

// i'm not sure what your outer result type is, so i've
// just named it 'collection'
const collections = [{id: "1",
    stories: [{
        id: "11",
        items: [{ id:"111", title:"bla bla" },{ id:"222", title:"bla bla" },{ id:"333", title:"bla bla" }]
    }]
}]
const normalized = normalize(collections, arrayOf(collection));
/* normalized === {
  "entities": {
    "collections": {
      "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "stories": [
          "11"
        ]
      }
    },
    "stories": {
      "11": {
        "id": "11",
        "items": [
          "111",
          "222",
          "333"
        ]
      }
    },
    "items": {
      "111": {
        "id": "111",
        "title": "bla bla"
      },
      "222": {
        "id": "222",
        "title": "bla bla"
      },
      "333": {
        "id": "333",
        "title": "bla bla"
      }
    }
  },
  "result": [
    "1"
  ]
} */
```

The `result` key tells you that you have received one collection with the id of 1. From there you can index into the `entities` key, which has been flattened by id. For more on how to then use this in your dispatcher, check https://github.com/gaearon/normalizr#explanation-by-example.

Disclaimer: I have not used normalizr, but since it was written by Dan Abramov (author of Redux) I think you'll be in good hands.